# How to examine the new line characters in emacs?

Tags: newlines

I want to check if there is a "\r" at the end of a line of a plain text file (compressed as .gz file). I try the whitespace mode, and I don't find `^M` shown. Is `\r` shown as `^M` in whitespace mode?

[image]

But my python program says something is wrong with the `1` at the end of the second line

```
line 67, in transform
    vals = [eval(v) for v in line.replace('\n', '').split(',')]
  File "<string>", line 1
    1
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Did I use emacs correctly to show the `\r`, `\n` and other characters at the end of each line?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the left side of the modeline, you'll see `(DOS)`. This means that Emacs is viewing the buffer as if it had DOS-style line endings. To view the buffer as if it had Unix-style line endings, use the command `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` (bound to `C-x RET r` or `C-x C-m r`), and select something like `utf-8-unix`. Then the `^M` characters will be visible.

Alternatively, if you want to convert the file to Unix-style line endings, use `set-buffer-file-coding-system` (`C-x RET f`/`C-x C-m f`) and choose `utf-8-unix`, then save the buffer.

From the Emacs manual, 22.6 Recognizing Coding Systems:

> Emacs recognizes which kind of end-of-line conversion to use based on the contents of the file: if it sees only carriage-returns, or only carriage-return linefeed sequences, then it chooses the end-of-line conversion accordingly. You can inhibit the automatic use of end-of-line conversion by setting the variable inhibit-eol-conversion to non-nil. If you do that, DOS-style files will be displayed with the ‘^M’ characters visible in the buffer; some people prefer this to the more subtle ‘(DOS)’ end-of-line type indication near the left edge of the mode line (see eol-mnemonic).

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html

Comment: Thanks. What caused emacs to use DOS instead of UNIX encoding to display the text file by default?

Comment: @Tim It's detected automatically.

Comment: @Tim I added in some info from the Emacs manual about changing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize newlines in emacs, activate `whitespace-newline-mode`, a minor mode associated with [whitespace-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace).